# How to do angularjs if statement?

Tags: angularjs, if-statement

I've got this code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<div ng-app="" ng-controller="Test">
<input type="text" ng-model="inputty">
<p>{{output}}</p>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>    
<script>
  function Test($scope){
    if($scope.inputty=="Hello") {
      $scope.output="OK!";
    } else {
      $scope.output="NOT OK!";
    }
  }
</script>
</html>
```

But it's not working, the `NOT OK!` displays. But it's like the if statement can't read from `inputty`. So it should state `OK!` when I type `Hello` in the input box.

Comment: `$scope.output = function(){ return $scope.inputty=="Hello" ?"OK!" : "NOT OK!"; }` and do `<p>{{output()}}</p>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add in a watch in your controlller in order to check the value of inputty and inside the watch function have the if loop so that you can change the output scope variable

Code:

```
function Test($scope) {
    $scope.inputty = '';
    $scope.$watch('inputty', function () {
        if ($scope.inputty == "Hello") {
            $scope.output = "OK!";
        } else {
            $scope.output = "NOT OK!";
        }
    });
}
```

[Working Fiddle -  $watch](http://jsfiddle.net/v01dsc7r/)

Reference for [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Alternatively,

You can do it alone in HTML markup using ng-switch

HTML markup

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Test">
    <input type="text" ng-model="inputty" />
    <div ng-switch="inputty">
        <p ng-switch-when="Hello">OK!</p>
        <p ng-switch-default>NOT OK!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle - ng-switch](http://jsfiddle.net/v01dsc7r/2/)

Reference for [ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new angular, is there an easier way to do this? I would have thought using a loop wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Its not a loop its a watcher function which will check the value of inputty ( an event in controller) so that controller then can check the value and set the output variable accordingly, otherwise an event needs to be thr in order to let the controller do the comparision

Comment: WHy watch/ng-switch etc.. it should be as simple as `return $scope.inputty=="Hello" ?"OK!" : "NOT OK!";`

Comment: In best practice, you should avoid polluting controller's with $watch. Once you have everything refactored into their file instead of all inline on the one html page, everything starts to get easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you only change your `inputty` through textbox, the easiest way is to use [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange).